# When you use the structure "I need you to do ...", who is in need of doing it? You or me?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, modal-verbs, idiomatic-language

If something is a necessity for someone, we can simply say to them:
**"You need to do ..."**

That is quite clear. But I often hear a structure **"I need you to do it"**, and I want to find out the reason why we need such a structure. *For example, a teacher at the end of the class says to one of the students, who is still playing with the blocks*,

**"Jenna I see you are still playing. I need you to put the blocks away."**

Why does the teacher say **"I need you to ...."?** Is it the teacher who is in need of doing something or is it the student who is in need of doing something. I mean, if putting the blocks away is a necessity, then simply **"You need to put the blocks away"** would work, wouldn't it? Why do we need a structure like **"I need you to do something."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rhetorical choice of words.  Making a demand: "You must..."  or using an imperative: "Do something" are direct and confrontational.  They can lead to an argument.

On the other hand, by speaking about your own requirement, saying  "I need..." makes this less confrontational.

Literally it says that the speaker needs something, and the thing that the speaker needs is the action of the person spoken to.

There are lots of phrases that teachers use to modify the behaviour of their students, without being drawn into an argument. If the teacher says "You need to put the blocks away", the child might respond "why do I need this.  I don't think I need this. I know about my needs, and you don't." By phrasing as "I need you to put the blocks away" the teacher shifts the need from the child to the teacher.  The child can't argue back, based on their own perception of their needs, since the need is with the teacher.

There are probably similar rhetorical techniques used by teachers in your language, so this isn't specific to English.

Comment: very well explained. I appreciate your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

When person A says 'I need you to *do something*' to person B, that means that person A is instructing or requesting person B to do something. It is a more urgent way of saying 'I want you to do *something*', and is very often an instruction from someone in authority, e.g. from a boss, supervisor, parent, teacher, etc.

Comment: Thanks and I am suprised to learn that it is more urgent way of saying "I want you to do smt". Yes, almost all situations I have heard this structure being used was a rushing situation. That is interesting. Why don't anybody tell us about this simple aspect in grammar books.

Comment: @yunus - 'need' just has its normal meaning of 'to have to have something, or to want something very much'. It's dictionary work.